# ForeignKey fields are not updated in one POST request

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I have a model in Django which has foreign key references to other models,

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    commentId = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    chatType = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    commentContents = get_nullable_text_field()
    timeStamp = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    userName=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    profilepicurl=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    userId=models.ForeignKey(Userprofile,default=None, blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    streamId=models.ForeignKey(Streams,default=None, blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    history = AuditlogHistoryField(pk_indexable=False)
```

now when I make a POST request in django rest framework, it takes all the data fields except streamID and userID(which are foreignkeys),this statred happening after i changed streamID and userID from models.charfield to models.ForeignKey. It works when i send a second POST request with the same body.

This is the serializer class

```
class CommentsSerializer(GlanceSerializer):
commentId = serializers.CharField(required=True)
@transaction.atomic()
def update_or_create(self, validated_data, create_only):
    id_field_value = {'commentId': validated_data['commentId']}
    data, _ = do_update_or_create(validated_data, create_only,
                                  Comments, id_field_value)
    return data

class Meta:
    model = Comments
    fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 0):

To update foreignkey, you must send a primary key of userId/streamId instead of string. I hope that will help you to solve your issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).